# How to remove the white space under my page when zooming in on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a responsive website, everything works fine except when I pinch zoom in on mobile and scroll down, there's a big white bar under my entire page that stretches across the entire width of my screen. How do I get rid of this? Here's my footer code:

```
    <footer id="footer">
    <img id="footer-logo" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="White-Tails Icon">
    <h4 style="vertical-align:bottom;">Copyright © West Shore White-Tails 2019</h4>
    <h3 id="check-out-sm">Check out our Social Media!</h3>
    <div class="tooltip">
      <span class="tooltiptext">Visit Facebook</span>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/ClubWscc"><img src="imgs/fbIcon.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">
      <span class="tooltiptext">Visit Twitter</span>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/ClubWscc"><img src="imgs/twitterIcon.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></a>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

My entire page is structured as

```
<body>
<wrapper>
  <other crap>
</wrapper>
```

It's also worth noting that the scrollbar doesn't appear in this white area...

Edit: heres relative css

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../imgs/bg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #080808;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: static;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it can come from the css. Can you add your css for the body, html and all the footer's elements? Also, what you can do is to inspect element as a mobile device (in the chrome browser) and see what creates this space.

Comment: It doesn't show in desktop browser.. the best way to explain is that it's like a "double scroll"...like you can scroll the foreground (like you should), but can also scroll the background. Even though its fixed. Edited op with some css

Comment: Added an image too